# Laravel Filament "/admin" 404 not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I uploaded my Laravel(v10.10) with Filament(v3) project to a website. To run the filament admin panel. The site is working, but when I go to /admin, I get 404 not found error. My project is functioning correctly on my local environment, but when I deployed it on the server.

Models/Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Filament\Panel;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Filament\Models\Contracts\HasName;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Filament\Models\Contracts\HasAvatar;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Filament\Models\Contracts\FilamentUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements FilamentUser, HasName, HasAvatar
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function canAccessPanel(Panel $panel): bool
    {
        return $this->hasRole('Admin');

    }

    public function getFilamentName(): string
    {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
    }

    public function getFilamentAvatarUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->avatar_url;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you run your database migrations in prod? Do the Spatie permissions tables exist? Do any of the users you're trying to access the panel with have that `Admin` role?

Comment: Hi @simonhamp yes i did. but i manage to sort it. my issue was the server. i had to `sudo a2enmod rewrite` , `sudo apache2ctl -t` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and it worked

Comment: Ah `mod_rewrite` wasn’t configured. Glad you got it sorted! You should create an answer and mark it as the accepted answer when you can so others can see quickly what the solution was

Comment: I did thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to sort it. my issue was the server. i had to run the following command on my terminal (one by one).

`sudo a2enmod rewrite` 

`sudo apache2ctl -t` 

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`